# Spring Cloud Config Cache updating collectively for unapproved changes on unintended services

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

Is this a real problem?

We have apps consisting of dozens of loosely related microservices that use a single git repo and get deployed together on a single VM. Since the cloud config service uses a cache that updates from the repo when there are changes, one changed service pulls the whole repo, sometimes including changes in another service's configs that weren't approved for deployment. As a result, unapproved changes make it into the cache, and any unscheduled restart causes the other service to load them.

We've switched most teams to local configs, which fixes it for this admittedly broken configuration.

We're planning to move to env vars for the variances to handle it when we move back to orchestration with containers. Other suggestions welcome, but either I am missing some fundamental item in the Spring Cloud spec, or there is just insufficient documentation around this particular vulnerability. Is there a simple solution *in* the cloud spec? Spring Cloud Bus *helps*, but doesn't really solve the problem.

I'm trying to make a stand on this - we have a known vulnerability where unapproved changes have been introduced and brought down our testing environments, but the response I get is "If cloud config is broken, why is Spring still supporting it?" The problem isn't spring, it's the set of options selected.

What am I missing? Am I just Chicken Little screaming about acorns? We've *seen* it take down the testing env, so I don't think so. Is there some critical bit that I'm just not wrapping my head around?

Comment: Why can't projects have their own repository rather than a single shared repo?

Comment: If you mean a single repo for every service, that's  one solution, but it's not the architecture that was in place when I was hired. We already have dozens of repos, and that would explode it to hundreds - there's a lot of resistance to that. I could also handle it in the automation with a tag per service per deployment, which is effectively the same, and my deployment automation would handle setting and tracking the tags and building the startup scripts that set the appropriate labels to pull them, but our team thinks local configs are FAR preferable. Everyone has switched but one dev team...

Comment: ok, calling it a broken architecture feels a bit extreme when the user has chosen a particular way of using it when there are other ways of configuration that don't have these problems.

Comment: I just mean this particular combination of choices. Spring is fine, I'm not saying the tools are no good. I'm saying the specific architecture that has been built is flawed. We have several valid possible solutions; I just want to know if I'm misunderstanding the problem.